# VS 2022 publishing to docker registry: Error response from daemon: No such image

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2022

I have a server that is configured to be a docker registry (following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-20-04)). Now I want to publish a project (which is part of a docker-compose file) in Visual Studio 2022 to this registry. I go with the publish wizard and I choose "Docker Container Registry" > "Other Docker Container Registry" and I provide the URL, username and password.

This is what I get:

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Running the docker.exe tag command failed.
>
> Error response from daemon: No such image: gateway:latest

How can I deploy my docker-compose projects to my server?

### Edit:

When I use command-line to push the generated image by VS, it works fine:

```
> docker push mydomain/gateway
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [mydomain/gateway]
...
```

But VS can't publish it.

Comment: Do you have an image with the name gateway:latest?

Comment: Locally I have `mydomain/gateway:latest` and `mydomain/gateway:dev` which were generated by VS. These names are from the compose file.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem using visual studio 2022 17.8

Comment: Nevermind i had wrong image name in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

check the URL again. follow the proper path.